# Delete all files within a directory, without deleting the directory

Tags: linux, delete

I have a directory called `outer`.

`outer` contains a directory named `inner` (which contains lots of files of same extension)

I `cd` to `outer`. How can I delete all the files within `inner` but leave the directory `inner` remaining (but empty)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to delete a directory's contents and not the directory itself, all you need to do is tell `rm` to delete the contents:

```
rm inner/*
```

That will delete all non-hidden files in `./inner` and leave the directory intact. To also delete any subdirectories, use `-r`:

```
rm -r inner/*
```

If you also want to delete hidden files, you can do (assuming you are using bash):

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -r inner/*
```

That last command will delete all files and all directories in `inner`, but will leave `inner` itself intact.

Finally, note that you don't need to `cd` to `outer` to run any of these:

```
$ tree -a outer/
outer/
├── dir
└── inner
    ├── dir
    ├── file
    └── .hidden

3 directories, 2 files
```

I can now run `rm -r outer/inner/*` from my current directory, no need to `cd outer`, and it will remove everything except the directory itself:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ rm -r outer/inner/*
$ tree -a outer/
outer/
├── dir
└── inner

2 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Using the wildcard for this purpose won't work if there are a lot of entries in that directory. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712128/353102 is a better solution.

Comment: @user582175 only if you have hundreds of thousands of files there, and only if you are using GNU find since the delete option isn't portable. But yes, if both those things are true, you need workarounds like that find command.

Answer (score 6):

```
find inner -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.

Comment: … and explain, if you can,  why you believe that this answer is *better* than the previous answers featuring ```find```.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' 1. It deletes not only files but directories too. 2. It doesn't require to specify inner directory name twice. 3. Compared to `rm` with glob it removes dot files too, it doesn't fail with "Argument list too long" on big list of files.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete all files under some directory structure, but keep all directories, the easiest is to use `find`'s `-delete` switch:

```
find /path/to/outer -type f -delete
```

To first check what would be deleted, just leave out the `-delete` at the end.

Comment: Simple and effective solution. I use it when deleting in /var/log directory

Answer (score 1):

```
find inner ! -path inner -delete
```

This would traverse the `inner` directory and delete everything.  The `! -path inner` test makes sure that the `inner` directory itself is not deleted (but all its contents *is* deleted).

The above would work on Linux with GNU `find` (the default `find`).  The `-delete` action is however non-standard (albeit commonly implemented).  For a standard compliant variation, use

```
find inner -depth ! -path inner -exec rm -r {} +
```

The `-depth` option makes sure that `find` does a depth-first traversal of the directory structure.  Without this, you may end up trying to delete directories before they are empty.

Comment: Note that `-delete` comes from BSDs, not GNU initially IIRC.

Comment: `-path` is not documented for AIX's (primitive) `find` command, but appears to work anyway.  You could also cd to inner and then use `find . -depth ! -name . -exec rm -r {} +`

Answer (score 0):

I use this loop alot, this way you can apply to any number of folders, don't even need to wory!

```
for i in `ls`; do rm -f $i/*; done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that this approach is prone to stumbling upon directory names with special characters (in particular, spaces), see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/377345) for further reading. Also, it will unnecessarily iterate over _files_ in the current directory and try to delete their "directory content".

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work with files that have a space in the name. Thanks for the link, it's very helpful! I was trying to find a simple one-liner solution. I even though about working with inodes but it would not be cleaner than the answers given here. Thanks for the help and the welcome :)

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```bsh
cd inner
ls -A | xargs -I {} rm -r "{}"
```

Edit: DO NOT USE. This has security issues if the filename contains quotes or newlines. (Code injections for example)

Comment: This does not handle names with spaces or quotes. I believe it may misbehave and delete files outside of the top directory if given specially crafted filenames.

Comment: @Kusalananda, backslashes and filenames starting with `-` would also be a problem, however, I don't think it could delete files outside the top directory. `xargs` may end up passing `..` as one argument to `rm`, however `rm` implementations are meant to reject those.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm away from computers at the moment, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry for not considering this. How about `ls -A | xargs -I {} rm -r "{}"`?

Comment: @searchstar You can test your solution on files created in these ways: `touch '"hello world"'` (filename containing quotes), and `touch $'hello\nworld'` (filename containing newline).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. The issues really shock me.